# Read property form file using spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I read a property from file as:

```
 private @Value("#{externalConfigProperties['myProperty'].split(',')}")
 List<Integer> myProperty;
```

but I would like to implement a little error control, How can I cacth a NumberFormatException?, For instance if this is my property to read.

```
 myProperty=1,e,5
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to add error handling so that you can catch that there is a value that is NOT an `Integer` before trying to place it into `myProperty` and causing RunTime Exceptions?

Comment: Just to be clear, just wondering if by error the property set some value no valid is possible catch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will throw a NumberFormatException when it will try to inject the values during the context initialization of the application.

You could do the following:

Define a setter method which takes a List of Strings instead of a List of Integers,
then move the value annotation from the variable declaration to the method, like this:

```
@Value("#{externalConfigProperties['myProperty'].split(',')}")
public void setMyProperty(List<String> myProperty) {
    this.myProperty = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String t:myProperty) {
        try {
            this.myProperty.add(Integer.valueOf(t));
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

The conversion of the values of the property from String to Integer is done in the method, and you can handle the NumberFormatException as you wish.

Comment: Yes, but I don´t konw catch it

Comment: Why would you need to handle this exception? You could just correct you properties file.

Comment: You're right but this file can edit it a lot of people

Comment: Each time the property file is edited, the application will need a restart for the change to take effect. In that way if there is an error the app will not start properly and someone will need to update it with a correct value.

Comment: Aifa, so far that id the solution.

Comment: Without changing the default way that spring bean initialization is done, you can do something like what I have added in the response.